# Bind error although SO_REUSEADDR was used and the socket was closed

Tags: ruby, sockets

There is the following code:

```
class ServerWrapper
    def run
        # create a TCP socket with the SO_REUSEADDR option and start listening
        @sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM)
        @sock.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        @sock.bind(Socket.sockaddr_in(9000, '0.0.0.0'))
        @sock.listen(1024)

        # listen for the socket changes in select
        Thread.new do
            IO.select [@sock], nil, nil, nil
        end.join
    end

    def close
        @sock.close
    end
end

@a = ServerWrapper.new
@server_thread = Thread.new { @a.run }
sleep 1
@a.close

# repeat the step as above
@a = ServerWrapper.new
@server_thread = Thread.new { @a.run } # <- here it will break with an error
sleep 1
```

This will print the error:

```
`bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:9000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

when trying to bind the second socket. The first socket was closed and also the option `Socket::SO_REUSEADDR` was used, why then there is the bind error here? It looks that the new thread with `select` function influences it.

Comment: Do a `Thread.list` after your first run, and you'll see that you still have three threads running. i.e. `@a.close` is not causing your run thread to finish, so the socket will still exist. You need a way to tell your run thread to finish.